# How would you process a recorded video with openCV on android

Tags: android, opencv

How would you process a recorded video with openCV on android, I want to process the video in non-real time as I need to process high quality video

Comment: In Java I've done this with videoio.VideoCapture (opencv 3.0).  You can get each frame and metadata about the frame for an mp4.  I'm hoping you can do the same on Android, but I've read things that make me wonder.  In particular I'm not sure the underlying ffmpeg libs needed to decode videos are there for android.  Have you made any progress?

Comment: I think you are right there is no support for opencv android yet to read and write video. The best solution I found was to use javacv instead of opencv which has ffmpeg support. Javacv is the pretty much the same as opencv as far as I can see. For instance Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, hsv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV); --opencv opencv_imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, hsv, opencv_imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV); --javacv. I could not find a way to convert javacv mat to opencv mat so I think if you need this functionality better stick to javacv and convert any opencv

Comment: I'm not so sure it's not there in opencv 3.0.  I noticed that opencv 2.4.x's VideoCapture for Android doesn't have a constructor that takes a filename, but 3.0 does have that constructor.  So that makes me think they might have ffmpeg working to decode videos in 3.0 on android.